# What is the name of that ES6 feature where you use the spread syntax in object literals?

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I think this is valid ES6:

```
o = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};

p = {
  ...o,   // <---
  c: 3
};

// now p == {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

As it seems this feature is not included in [Babel's `es2015` preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/). Investigating further, I was trying to find out under what conditions [Babel's `env` preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/) would include it.

This requires me to locate the feature in the [ES6 compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/), but I cannot find it. What is its name?

Comment: `...` is not an operator!

Answer (score 1):

Object spread is not ES6. It is [stage 3 proposal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_object_literals), not a part of existing spec.

It can be enabled in Babel with `stage-3` (or lower) preset.

It can be monitored in ES compatibility table, [ES.next tab](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/#test-object_rest/spread_properties).

Comment: Even though it is available in Chrome.

Comment: That's correct, most proposals already have browser implementations at the time they reach stage 4.

Answer (score 0):

[Rest/Spread Properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) is the name of the specification proposal.

The reason you can't find it in the ES6 table is because it is only currently a **Stage 3 proposal** and not part of the ES6 spec. You need to look in the Next section:

http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/#test-object_rest/spread_properties